# Count exception thrown in Python

Tags: python, exception

For my exception handling I actually want to have a concept of a `finally` statement which is only called when an exception happened (and not like the real finally statement which is called in all cases).

Here is a short sketch:

```
class ErrorA(Exception):
    pass

class ErrorB(Exception):
    pass

error_counter = 0

try:
    raise ErrorA # or raise ErrorB
except ErrorA:
    print('ErrorA')
    error_counter += 1
except ErrorB:
    print('ErrorB') # some error handling for ErrorB
    error_counter += 1
```

I need to react on every `Exception` differently (in this sketch represented by `print`)

Is there something more pythonic? For me it looks weird that I need `error_counter += 1` in all `Exception` cases.

Comment: You could change to `except Exception as exc:` then use `if isinstance(exc, ...)` within that to group behaviour based on specific error types.

Comment: Would `ok = False; try: ..... ok = True;` then after `except`, `if not ok: error_counter += 1` be more Pythonic for you? Or you can wrap and extra `try: ... except Exception: error_counter += 1; raise`